# How do you take User Input in a text box and use it to perform math in Kotlin?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm building an android app that calculates commission for employees. I can't figure out how to call the user input and use it to perform the math. What I'd like to happen is they input all the numbers in each field, then click on the calculate button. That should call the first input field and multiply it by 5, then the second input field and multiply by 7.5 etc until all six user input fields have been multiplied by a set number, then it should add them all together and dump them into the "Payout" field. I just cant seem to find a place to start. If anyone could put me on the right path, I'd appreciate it. Code snippets below for a bit of extra context.

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="207dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:text="@string/calculate"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextNumber7" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNumber7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/payout"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextNumber4" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your kotlin class you should find button and every edit text by its id:

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
//...
val editText7 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextNumber7)
```

To define what will happen if the button is  clicked you should set its OnClickListener:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
        //what to do when the button is clikced
}
```

To get text from specific editText you should do:

```
val text7 = editText7.text
```

To convert it to int do the following:

```
val number7 = text7.toString().toInt()
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the guidance! I went through and finished everything up to the third snippet of code and I'm working on figuring out how to do the int conversion.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if users are only able to put in integers, do I need to convert still or can I just go ahead and math?

Comment: @BlakeWord Sorry, I forgot to explain this. `editText.text` is returning `Editable`, so to get text as a string you need to do`editText.text.toString()`, and if you want int `editText.text.toString().toInt()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! You put me on the right path and I finished the full product today. Much appreciated!